# How to regulate threads inside a "for" loop?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multithreading

I have the following problem:
I am running a large process with threading which involves importing a pair of files, calculating and giving back a score. this is all in a TKinter Python API.

For single pairs it works fine:

```py
def run_single():
    #importing , calculating and scoring
    couple = [path1,path2]
    th_score = threading.Thread(target= scoring_function)
    th_score.start()
  ...
```

The problem is when i want to do stock imports: Importing two directories, making pairs of the same file references and operating each pair in a loop. I want to do threading for each individual iteration and start with the next pair of files only when all the threads from the previous scoring process are done. I tried:

```py
def run_multiple():
    for pair in couples:
        couple = pair.copy()
        th_score = threading.Thread(target= scoring_function)
        th_score.start()
```

This was wrong because of the threads not synchronizing, running some threads over others already running. Threading continues with the `for` loop even when the execution of `scoring_function` in the current iteration is not finished (yeah, I know that's threading's purpose).

I tried using conditions and events, even using them as global variables so the `scoring_function` could regulate them, but all they do is freezing the program.

Any suggestion on what I should use?

Comment: There's really two issues with what you're trying to do. The main one is primarily about thread synchronization and the other has to do with doing multi-threading within a tkinter GUI application. I strong suggest that you first create a [mre] that demonstrates the threading issue and, once that's solved, work on doing in a tkinter GUI (and asking another question if you can't figure that part out).

Answer (score 0):

From my experience the best way of doing threading is to use the `threading.Thread` class of python along with this little trick:

```
import threading

couples = [1,2,3]  # probably a list you created with some elements

class run_in_thread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        for pair in couples:
            couple = pair.copy()


wanted_threads = 3
for a in range(wanted_threads):
    instance = run_in_thread()
    instance.start()
```

In this case, you start three threads.
You use the built in `run()` function from threading.

`threading.Thread` class that is by default will create a new thread by executing it later with `start()`.

I hope this helps.

More documentation of correct threading see: [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)